# Clone element title attribute from sibling into data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a page I have numerous DIVs with a class 'results-block'. (dozens)

Inside each of these results-block DIVs, there's a  element which contains a link element that has a title attribute set already - in the example below, there's two of these result-block DIVs, one for 'Company A' and another for 'Company B'.

Further down but still inside each of the results-block DIVs, there's a UL with several a link elements - these currently HAVE no data-id attribute. (need to add that via JQ)

My question - how do I add a data-id attribute to each of the link elements in the footer first, then use JQ to scrape the page and assign what's set as the title attribute for the a link (contained in the closet sibling header) to each of the a links within the footer (ul list). So for Company A, each of the a link elements will get a data-id of 'Company A', and for Company B each of the a link elements will get a data-id of 'Company B'.

I've tried a few things but nothing seems to be working - a combination of .parent and .closest. Starting to wonder if this is even possible in JQ, or if I need to resort to JS.

```
<div class="results-block">
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="company-name" title="Company A">Company A</a>
  </header>
  <div class="head-info"></div>
  <footer>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company A'</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company A'</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
 </footer>
</div>

<div class="results-block">
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="company-name" title="Company B">Company A</a>
  </header>
  <div class="head-info"></div>
  <footer>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company B'</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company B'</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
 </footer>
</div>


$(".results-block footer ul li a").attr("data-id", $(".results-block header a").closest(1).attr("title"));
```

Comment: So, the footer links should get a data-id and title equal to their header links title?  Also, *"Starting to wonder if this is even possible in JQ, or if I need to resort to JS.*.  jQuery **is** javascript

Comment: exactly! I've been at this for hours. I'm a new coder still learning and I thought this would be fairly easy - reading has not cleared my confusion on selecting/targeting nearby element attributes.

Comment: ah yes thanks for clarification, I was reading on some SO threads that closest/parent does not work the same in JQ as it does in straight up JS. Educate me please!

Answer (score 1):

You are close but there are two main problems with your approach

1. You aren't looping over instances. Can fix this by using `attr(attrName, function)` which will run that function for every matching element
2. closest() only works in one direction. You can't look up  and then down in same css traverse. Instead look up with closest() and then use `find()` to change directions

```js
  $(".results-block footer ul li a").attr("data-id", function(){
       return $(this).closest(".results-block").find("header a").attr("title");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results-block">
      <header>
        <a href="#" class="company-name" title="Company A">Company A</a>
      </header>
      <div class="head-info"></div>
      <footer>
           <ul>
              <li>
                 <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company A'</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company A'</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
     </footer>
    </div>

    <div class="results-block">
      <header>
        <a href="#" class="company-name" title="Company B">Company A</a>
      </header>
      <div class="head-info"></div>
      <footer>
           <ul>
              <li>
                 <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company B'</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company B'</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
     </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.
Thanks much for the help and the learning.

Comment: @user3850554 don't forget to accept the answer. This help future viewer see this answer faster (plus some external client read only accepted solution)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the result blocks, get the title that you want and put them on the footer links that belong to the result block.  You will not see the 'data-id' if you inspect the elements, as jquery stores data fields in memory, but if you console log their data variable you will see they are present.

```js
$('.results-block').each(function(index, element){
  var headerTitle = $(element).find('header a').attr('title');
  
  $('footer a', element).attr('title', headerTitle).data('id', headerTitle);

  $('footer a', element).each(function(index, element){
      console.log(element.title, $(element).data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results-block">
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="company-name" title="Company A">Company A</a>
  </header>
  <div class="head-info"></div>
  <footer>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company A'</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company A'</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
 </footer>
</div>

<div class="results-block">
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="company-name" title="Company B">Company A</a>
  </header>
  <div class="head-info"></div>
  <footer>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company B'</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" >Add data-id that = 'Company B'</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
 </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!
And now I much more understand looping and closest().